# Do WP 8.0 apps appear in WP Store to users with WP 8.1

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, store

I am developing an application. I want to target the widest user base possible but I do not know for which platform I should develop. I fear that if I develop an app for WP 8.0, users with WP 8.1 won't be able to download it (or see it in the  store).

In app I am using some multithreading features that are present in WP 8.0 and WP 8.1 Silverlight (but not in WP 8.1) and I am not sure how the Windows Phone Store manages the apps.

Are WP 8.0 apps available to WP 8.1 users? The WP 8.0 version of the app does work on my WP 8.1 phone.

For Android things are really straightforward... If app uses API 15, users with API 15 and 15+ can download it and use it, for WP I am not sure.

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Apps developed for a lower version will work on newer ones. You can still install WP7 and WP8 apps on Windows Phone 8.1 and also Windows 10 Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going with the newer WP8.1 format.  That will let you build as a universal app, which will be runnable on Windows as well as WP.  WP 8.1 is quickly supplanting WP 8.0.  It was on the majority of Lumia devices last [year](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2373042/microsoft-windows-phone-81-is-on-majority-of-lumia-devices). Windows 10 is just around the corner.  I haven't really looked at developing WP 10 apps, but I imagine it will be less work to port from WP 8.1 to WP 10.